# How to display/show Static HTML file in apache superset?

Tags: apache-superset

Have a couple of static HTML files and would like to display
them in Apache Superset.

Is there an easy way (vs modifying the code).

Comment: Are you looking to display the content in one of the dashboards?

Comment: Yes, potentially to display in the dashboard.
Just need to display static HTML in some way